# Application very slow/crashes when zooming using Android ScaleGesture in OpenGL ES onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) method

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am developing an Android app using OpenGL ES 2.0 and have encountered a problem that whenever I try zooming in or out of an image, it does zoom but the app responds very sluggishly and eventually crashes without an error message. Scale gesture events are handled through the onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) method of my GLSurfaceView class:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
    if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()){
    mRenderer.processTouchEvent(e);}//touchstate being what happens when a touch event occurs
    return true;
}
```

Here is the scale listener class:

```
public class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener  {
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    AppFragment.scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

    // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
    AppFragment.scaleFactor = Math.max(1f, Math.min(AppFragment.scaleFactor, 10.0f));

    AppFragment.xFocus=detector.getFocusX();
    AppFragment.yFocus=detector.getFocusY();

    AppFragment.HAS_BEEN_MAGNIFIED=true;

    AppFragment.mGLSurfaceView.requestRender();



    return true;
}
```

}

Any suggestions as to what could be causing this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Please attach the error log.

Comment: You are probably missing a lot of code here. The first thing that comes to mind is that you are changing the size of the surface which you should not do. If you are using matrices and ortho (which seems the correct way in your case) then all you need to do is change the ortho values on scale. For instance if your start values are (0,320,480, 0...) and you scale around center by 2.0 then the result should be (80, 160, 240, 120...).